# Как быстро обновить данные через Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ado.net

Пишу запрос вот такого вида:

```
   if (storage.Folders.Any(x => x.DateDeleted == null))
            {
                storage.Folders.Where(x => x.DateDeleted == null).ToList().ForEach(x => x.DateDeleted = DateTime.Now);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
```

И я так и не смог дождаться, пока выполниться `context.SaveChanges();`

Судя по тому, что ОЗУ заполняется на 400 мб, то я вытягиваю все к себе.

Можно ли сделать быстрое обновление? Или единственных выход рулить руками через `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand()` ?

Comment: @Bulson, а я не сравниваю. Я хочу всем записям проставить текущую дату удаления.

Comment: Виноват, невнимательно прочитал код.

Comment: EF не умеет bulk update (и insert). Да, придётся писать sql-запрос вручную в `ExecuteSqlCommand`, Или можно поискать библиотеку расширений для EF, скажем [EntityFramework.Extended](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended). Ну или вообще взять другую ORM, более правильную: [linq2db](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov На сколько linq2db шустрее?

Comment: Конечно, производительность зависит от типов запросов, но в целом большинство попробовавших linq2db восторженно отзываются о его скорости. Часто он оказывается быстрее Dapper, на котором работает stackoverflow.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, не думаю, что получу ответ лучше. Оформите как ответ. P.S А ничего не слышно про EF7? Вроде, как бета вышла в 2015, а до сих пор релиза не видно.

Comment: @iluxa1810, ну как же релиза не видно? Версия 1.1 в релизе, пожалуйста: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Roadmap

Comment: @СергейПолушин, хм... Они его переименовали. А по производительности он как по сравнению с 6 ?

Comment: @iluxa1810, не могу сказать, пока мало использовал. Но существенных отличий по скорости не должно быть.. Попробуйте сами, там переход совсем безболезненный)

Comment: Когда ещё планировалось название EF7, много писали, что код будет переписан полностью, именно с расчётом на максимальную производительность. Потом пошли версии _Core_, в которых упор сделан на кроссплатформенность, так что боюсь, производительность на втором плане. Хуже быть не должно, но вряд ли сильно лучше.

Answer (score 4):

Entity Framework не умеет выполнять массовые обновления и вставки (bulk update/insert).

Поэтому придётся писать sql-запрос вручную в `ExecuteSqlCommand`.

Можно поискать готовую библиотеку расширений для EF, в которой такие запросы уже реализованы. Например, широко известна [EntityFramework.Extended](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended).

Как вариант, можно вообще взять другую ORM, более правильную: [linq2db](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db).

Comment: А можете вот на этот вопрос ответить https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/675742/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-linq2db Вы, как я понимаю, пользовались этим ОРМ